# Angular 2-way binding in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable, ng-bind

I'm trying to update values in an ng-repeat with ng-bind (or double curly braces) and html5's contenteditable.

I cannot get the double binding to work. Don;t think contenteditable is the issue since it doesn't work either with input fields.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">     
    <ul><li ng-repeat="sequence in sequences"  sv-element>
            <span class="flex1" contenteditable="true" ng-bind="sequence.sequenceText"></span> // 
        <span  contenteditable="true">{{sequence.sequenceText}}</span>
    </li></ul>
{{sequences}}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56g2jyd7/1/

Comment: Use this library - https://github.com/akatov/angular-contenteditable it's wrapper of contentedtiable attribute for Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't want to use a directive but I eventually did.
Nice and easy:

```
app.directive('contenteditable', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      // view -> model
      element.bind('blur', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(element.html());
        });
      });

      // model -> view
      ctrl.$render = function() {
        element.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
      };

      // load init value from DOM
     ctrl.$render();
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tmx9Kr8PDKaS20vs2MKC?p=preview